# Play Audio Ringtone in Speaker

Tags: java, android, audio

I am using bellow code.It's working fine in other devices as ring is on the speaker of the device  but in Samsung it's inside the earpiece and not audible.

```java
MediaPlayer mAudioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.phone_loud1);
mAudioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mAudioPlayer.setLooping(true);
mAudioPlayer.start();

AudioManager  am;
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: Why are you passing a `STREAM` constant to `setMode`? You should be using one of the `MODE` constants.

Comment: @Michael,  tried with your suggestion but no luck. Can you please help me out with piece of code to play  Ring tone  for incoming VOIP (Sinch) call . My Applied code works well for other devices except SAMSUNG MODEL. In SAMSUNG the ring is in the earpiece and very low.